# Returning found char and index in list - Python

Tags: python, list, char, compare

I have the following code:

I am trying to compare each char in the userInputList with the Letters array, if found in the letters array i would like to return it along with its index number; so if a user was to type hello: it would check if 'h' exists in Letters which it does, return the value and also return the index of it which is 7.

At the moment my if function checks against the index and not the actual character so it will always return true.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
Letters = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o',
           'p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']

userInput = input("Please enter what you would like to deycrpt:")

userInputList = list(userInput)

for i in range(0,len(userInputList)):
    print(userInputList[i])
    if userInputList[i] in Letters:
        print("true")

    i+=1
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
# Python 2 users add the following line:
from __future__ import print_function

for letter in userInputList:
    print(letter, end=': ')
    try:
        print('found at index', Letters.index(letter))
    except ValueError:
        print('not found')
```

You can iterate directly over `userInputList` without using `i`.
The method `index` returns the index of the first found entry and raises an `IndexError` if the value is not in the list. So catch this error and print that the letter is not found. Finally, `print(letter, end=': ')` suppresses the newline at the end of the print an puts `:` there, which make the letter and the message from the next print appear on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

```
 x = ord(raw_input("Digit a key: ")) - 97
 if x < 26:
      print("found at %d" % x)
 else:
      print("Not found!")
```

Answer (score 0):

First, some comments:
don't use i+=1, the "for i in range loop" is already doing this for you.

You can also use :

```
for i, item in enumerate(userInputList):
```

to return you the index in the user list in **i** and the character at that index in **item**

then your check is good, but it's gonna give you with the for loop I gave you :

```
if item in Letters:
    print("{} is in position {}".format(item, i))
```

format function will replace the "{}" in the string by the values item and i ( in this order)

Is this what you are looking for ?